# GoogleMaps for iOS Linker Error

Tags: ios, google-maps

While building the Application i am getting the following error i have searched a lot but i am unable to figure out what is the problem.

> > ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/username/GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/username/GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps (2 slices)
> >     Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSPolyline", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in GPSController.o
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSCameraPosition", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in GPSController.o
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMutablePath", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in GPSController.o
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMarker", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in GPSController.o
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMapView", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in GPSController.o
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSServices", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
> >     ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
> >     clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am using GoolgeMaps SDK 1.4.3

PS:- I am relatively new to iOS programming so please avoid any blunders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I figured out the Problem
 My Library was not built for 64-bit but i was trying to use that settings for my app, after i removed arm64 from architecture i successfully build the application.

Comment: Beaware, you can't submit apps that doesn't support 64 bit starting february 2105.

Comment: is this really true? sadly i did not knew this :/

Comment: Yes, it's true. You would better support 64 bit archs.

Comment: @FahriAzimov ok i understand your answer but when i do use the google latest sdk it gives me the same linker error, so this is why i witched to 1.4 and google SDK 1.4 is not supporting 64-bit architectre. What You suggests what should i do?

Comment: All the latest Google libs and frameworks for iOS do support 64 bit. Try clean build, deleting derived data, and building again.

Comment: @FahriAzimov I am using the latest version but still this error occur. Any Solutions??

Comment: I am also having the linker error with the Google Maps. Did anybody found the solution ?

Comment: Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 6):

Adding value $(inherited) to BuildSettings->Linking->Other Linker Flags of your target

If you are developing an SDK/framework/POD you should do the same as above but under target name `PROJECTNAME_tests`.

Should fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too, and my solution was to add the frameworks to
 **Target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries**